# move all .cpp & .h in a filter to another project AND correct their folder location

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Here is **filter** of my project in Visual Studio shown in **Solution Explorer** :-

```
ProjectName1
== References, External Dependencies, Header Files, Resource Files
== Source Files
==== myFilter01
------ K.h               (system folder = `D:\ProjectName1\K.h`)
------ K.cpp             (system folder = `D:\ProjectName1\K.cpp`)   
==== myFilter02                                                 
====== subFilter2_1                                              
--------- B.h            (system folder = `D:\ProjectName1\B.h`)
--------- B.cpp          (system folder = `D:\ProjectName1\B.cpp`)   
========= subFilter2_2                                           
----------- C.h          (system folder = `D:\ProjectName1\C.h`)   
----------- C.cpp        (system folder = `D:\ProjectName1\C.cpp`)   
ProjectName2                                                   
== ... (some existing filter/files)
```

*(In real case, all filters contains a lot of sub-sub-filter and files.)*

### Question

How to :

- move all `.h` and `.cpp` files (`B` and `C`) inside `myFilter02` to `ProjectName2`'s **folder** (e.g. `D:\ProjectName2`)
- don't change appearance of the **filter** (e.g. `C` must be still in `subFilter2_1\subFilter2_2`)
- and do it in a few clicks (i.e. not depend on amount of files/sub-filters) i.e. `O(1)`

Here is the expected result :-

```
ProjectName1
== References, External Dependencies, Header Files, Resource Files
== Source Files
==== myFilter01
------ K.h               (system folder = `D:\ProjectName1\K.h` )
------ K.cpp             (system folder = `D:\ProjectName1\K.cpp` )   
==== myFilter02 
ProjectName2
== ... (some existing filter/files)       
== subFilter2_1                                                             
----- B.h                (system folder = `D:\ProjectName2\B.h` )
----- B.cpp              (system folder = `D:\ProjectName2\B.cpp` )
===== subFilter2_2                                             
------- C.h              (system folder = `D:\ProjectName2\C.h` )
------- C.cpp            (system folder = `D:\ProjectName2\C.cpp` )
```

It can be done manually for each sub-sub-sub-filter + add existing files, but it is very tedious.

I tried to right click the filter/files, but didn't found such feature.
I currently don't use any Microsoft's source control / repository (just in case it is related).

**Note:** The normal drag & drop on **filters** don't move the files to another project's **folder**.
It just makes the moved files to be a *shortcut* of the original location (`D:\ProjectName1\`).

Hotkey?  Plugin?  Script?
Do I really have to create a program to do this specific thing?

*A few days after asking, I have coded it with c++ using [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) ~ 500-1000 lines.

I have to edit `.vcxproj.filters` and `.vcxproj` of both projects, and move some system files.

I still find no answer about the question, though.*

### **Edit**

*(After receive advise from Hans Passant and  Prab, thank!)*
I want to use filter rather than folder for these reasons :-

- Source control is easier, because all source files are in a same directory.
- In Visual Studio, I can move files around different **filters** a little easier than around **folders**.
- With Filter, I don't have to lengthen `#include "../myFilter01/K.h"` or add **additional include directories** for each folder.   I can simple `#include "K.h"`.
- If I change the place where a file resides in a **filter**, I don't have to refactor it.
  In case of changing **folder**, I have to refactor code.
- I can use very strange character e.g.  `=◆██myFilter01██◆=` for filters but not folder.  It is my taste.

I don't want to

- **Use folder instead of filter :**   Beside difficulty of recreate many folders and move my `.cpp/.h` files manually, I will suffer the above disadvantages.
- **Use folder with same structure as filter :**  I have to keep it in sync together manually (all the time - tedious).  I will still get some the above disadvantages.

In summary, using **folder** instead of **filter** causes me more new trouble than it solves.

Comment: There isn't anything special about a filter, it is just a way to organize the view of the project in the Solution Explorer window.  It does not affect the location of the file nor does it affect the build.  If you spend more than 30 seconds on it then you are overdoing it.

Comment: if you want the files to be found under the new project's folder then the filter's not going to cut it. A filter is just that and nothing more. If you want to change the location on the hard drive then write a script to do it before creating the filter

Comment: @Hans Passant  Do you use the real folder instead of filter?  I think using real folder is 1. error-prone when create a new source file - I have to browse to a non-default directory.  2. Furthermore, #include would be a bit longer or I have to add "additional include directory" to every related folder.  (I am very new to VS project editor.)   If so, do you face these issues?

Comment: For new projects you can just copy your project and remove unnecessary files.

Comment: @Logman  It is a good idea for a small solution.   In my case,  I have to remove a lot of files (200-400) for both project manually, though.

Comment: @javaLover Yes I agree but it's has the same complexity as selecting and coping 200-400 files from one project to another. Btw. you can try to copy necessary files from one project to another then edit .filer files and copy elements from one file to another.

Comment: @Logman  It is mindless and exhaustive work. I wonder why Visual is so unfinished in many features.

Answer (score 0):

It's not one click solution but it could be done faster then manual.

1. Find out what file need to be copied. To do that move filters from one project to another. Then switch to directory view (show all files) for first project and copy but not past files with small red indicator (files that are not included in the project). Now get back to filter view for both project and move back filters to first project. After that switch both projects to directory view and do pass on second project.
2. Now we need to create correct filters. Move files from source and header filter to another filters in second project. Unload both projects. Open first and second project .filters files copy from first file to second all filter tags except "Source Files", "Header Files", "Resource Files". Next from second file remove all tags started with source or header. Now from second ItemGroup copy whole content and pass it to second file second ItemGroup. Save second file.
3. In this point you should have copy of first project filter tree without unnecessary files now just move what you want to correct places.

It is helpful to create single tree in first project.

Comment: The tedious-ness of this approach is `O(amount-of-file)`, right?

Comment: @javaLover ;). It's not perfect but is a lot faster then moving everything manually. You just need to select every file that are marked as not included and it could be boring. After that you just need to copy two blocks of text. And delete one block.